# Edit MAM stream already implemented on Tangle

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging

For my project, I have created a web interface on which I'm viewing a published MAM stream.

I want to know that is it possible to edit or add new record to MAM stream that has already been published on Tangle without changing its root? Is that even possible? If yes, then any leads on how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add new messages to a MAM stream by reloading the “mam state” and then simply publishing again.  here is an example using javascript

https://github.com/Evanfeenstra/helix/blob/master/mam.js#L181

Comment: How do I add this updated MAM message stream for the same seed?

Comment: What is next_root in this code?

Comment: I would like to mention that I want to update the data in existing MAM stream (already published to tangle) from a web interface.

Comment: The user will need to input the seed (but of course the seed never needs to leave the browser).  The next_root is returned from the previous MAM message

Comment: Could you please elaborate it a little bit? I don't get it.